# Decomposition of $f$ when $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal system that is complete

Tags: solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

If $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal system that is complete, then for every $f$ in a Hilbert space $H$, $\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle = 0$ implies $f = 0$. But how come that
$$f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle\varphi_n \ ? $$

I am aware that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle\varphi_n$ converges in $H$. Let $g = f - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle\varphi_n$, then for any $j \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align}
\langle g, \varphi_j \rangle &= \langle f - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle\varphi_n , \varphi_j\rangle\\
&= \langle f, \varphi_j\rangle - \langle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle\varphi_n , \varphi_j\rangle\\
&= \langle f, \varphi_j\rangle - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle}\langle \varphi_n, \varphi_j\rangle\\
&= \langle f, \varphi_j\rangle - \overline{\langle f, \varphi_j \rangle}\\
&= 2i\operatorname{Im}(\langle f, \varphi_j\rangle) = 0
\end{align}
Can I conclude that $g = 0$? I think I can because $g \in H$. But if someone can confirm it, I would be happy. Is there a mistake somewhere in my proof? Can I say that $\operatorname{Im}(\langle f, \varphi_j\rangle) = 0$?

Note: This question is similar to [Why every x in an Hilbert space with a complete orthonormal sequence can be written as this Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206081/why-every-x-in-an-hilbert-space-with-a-complete-orthonormal-sequence-can-be-writ), but the explanation why it is true is a bit different with mine. That's why I am not sure whether this is correct.

Comment: Which convention of linearity are you using? If it is linearity in the second variable as per line 3, then the formula should read $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle \phi_n,f\rangle\phi_n$. If you repeat the same derivation, you'll get $0$ without the imaginary part.

Comment: I used the rule $\langle c_1\textbf{x} + c_2\textbf{y}, \textbf{z}\rangle = \overline{c_1}\langle\textbf{x}, \textbf{z} \rangle + \overline{c_2}\langle\textbf{y}, \textbf{z} \rangle$ (Conjugate-linearity in the first factor)